# Is there any point clustering algorithm to collect points into nearby groups?

Tags: algorithm, gps, cluster-analysis, data-mining, photo

I am writing a iOS photo manage app.

I want to collect photos into groups by their GPS information. Then I can get the mean GPS information of a Group, and give the group a name, for example:Trip to　New York.

Is there any handy algorithm to collect nearby Photos into groups　by GPS information?

Comment: What's wrong with the standard kmeans algorithm? For example, 'http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dpelleg/kmeans.html'. You just have to adopt it to wrap around the edges. `R` would be an easy choice, as it has the algorithm implemented already.

Comment: k-means is not appropriate for this task. See below. a) you need to know k, b) every object *must* belong to a cluster c) every cluster has the same spatial extend, because it splits the data in Voronoi cells.

Answer (score 11):

Forget the usual reply of k-means. It's simple, but simply not appropriate for this task.

Have a look at [DBSCAN (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN). It's right on target for what you need. You can specify a radius (if you use the great circle distance, you can use meters!) and a minimum cluster size. If your clusters vary largly in density, and DBSCAN merges clusters it shouldn't, you can try [OPTICS (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OPTICS_algorithm), which will not even need the epsilon parameter, just a minimum cluster size. It does however produce *hierarchical* clusters. So you will have e.g. a cluster of eiffel tower pictures, inside of a cluster of Paris pictures.

A *nice* property of DBSCAN is that it has a concept of noise. Objects that do *not* belong to a cluster.

Comment: Provides great alternatives to the sterotype reply of "k-means clustering"

Comment: BIRCH is a suitable alternative to DBSCAN. It is implemented in [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.Birch.html]).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a spatial index or a space filling curve with a squared grid. It's similar to a quadtree and you can compute a quadkey or geohash for each gps pair. It's a tiling algorithm and subdivide the plane. It's also a hierarchical cluster.